# How to remove "unneeded" bytes of a ciphertext?

Tags: javascript, encryption, aes, cross-platform

I am using node-js and crypto library to encrypt/decrypt my strings with AES-128 encryption. But I have a problem, that's the pads to make a string multiple of 16 bytes. How can I remove those bytes? Because I can't use decrypted_string == "actual string" (because of the unneeded bytes at end of the string) in javascript. Here are the functions which I use to encrypt / decrypt strings in javascript:

```js
const crypto = require("crypto");

function encrypt(str, key) {
    let input = Buffer.from(str, "utf8");
    let token = Buffer.from(key);
    cipher = crypto.createCipheriv("aes-128-ecb", token, '');
    result = cipher.update(input).toString("base64");
    result += cipher.final().toString("base64");
    return result;
}

function decrypt(str, key) {
    let input = Buffer.from(str, "base64");
    let token = Buffer.from(key);
    decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv("aes-128-ecb", token, '');
    decipher.setAutoPadding(false);
    result = decipher.update(input).toString("utf8");
    result += decipher.final().toString("utf8");
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Simple set in "decipher.setAutoPadding(false);" from false to **true**

Comment: I mean, when I decrypt a string which I encrypted using this "encrypt" function from my c++ application, it decrypts a char array with 16 bytes length. Also those characters are not '\0' so the string becomes incorrect actually. Isn't there any solution else? I have problem with encrypting, not decrypting.

Comment: Encrypting and decrypting belong together. What you are describing is a **padding** issue and so you need to apply the same padding mode on encryption and decryption side. What has "c++" to do with the code to provided as it is Javascript/crypto code ??

Comment: *"How to remove “unneeded” bytes of a ciphertext?"* padding is needed for ECB mode. Sounds like your C++ application that you want to be compatible with implements zero padding instead of PKCS#7 padding which node.js uses by default.